# How to send multipart/mime SOAP request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, soap, mime

SOAP server requires multipart SOAP request with XML file like

```
    Content-type: multipart/related;boundary="MIME_boundary";type="text/xml"; start="<soapPart>"

        --MIME_boundary
        Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
        Content-ID: <soapPart>
            <env:Envelope
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:id="http://x-road.eu/xsd/identifiers"
            xmlns:xrd="http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd">
                <env:Header>
                    <xrd:client id:objectType="SUBSYSTEM">
                        <id:xRoadInstance>EE</id:xRoadInstance>
                        <id:memberClass>COM</id:memberClass>
                        <id:memberCode>00000000</id:memberCode>
                        <id:subsystemCode>misp-client</id:subsystemCode>
                    </xrd:client>
                    <xrd:service id:objectType="SERVICE">
                        <id:xRoadInstance>EE</id:xRoadInstance>
                        <id:memberClass>GOV</id:memberClass>
                        <id:memberCode>70000349</id:memberCode>
                        <id:subsystemCode>mkrliides</id:subsystemCode>
                        <id:serviceCode>uploadMime</id:serviceCode>
                        <id:serviceVersion>v1</id:serviceVersion>
                    </xrd:service>
                    <xrd:userId>EE00000000000</xrd:userId>
                    <xrd:id>4894e35d-bf0f-44a6-867a-8e51f1daa7e1</xrd:id>
                    <xrd:protocolVersion>4.0</xrd:protocolVersion>
                </env:Header>
                <env:Body>
                    <mta:uploadMime xmlns:mta="http://emta-v6.x-road.eu">
                        <request>
                            <target>KMD2</target>
                            <operation>Submit</operation>
                            <file href="cid:6f55eb41-7b72-40fe-bb7f-49bffefe9ae4"/>
                            <props>
                                <prop key="lang">et</prop>
                                <prop key="confirmation">TRUE</prop>
                            </props>
                        </request>
                    </mta:uploadMime>
                </env:Body>
            </env:Envelope>

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; flename=test.xml
Content-ID: <6f55eb41-7b72-40fe-bb7f-49bffefe9ae4>
<xml>test</xml>
--MIME_boundary--
```

Another sample is in https://ncfailid.emta.ee/s/bS2XCJMF3KtErpC/download/example-mime-request.xml

Code to use it is generated from WSDL below in Visual Studio.
Trying generated code using

```
 var cl = new webServiceInterfaceClient(new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport), new EndpointAddress("https://example.com"));
var rt = new UploadMimeRequestType()
{
  target = "target",
  operation = "operation",
  file = new UploadMimeRequestTypeFile() { href = "href", Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xml content") },
  props = new PropertiesProp[0]
};
var ulreg = new uploadMime() { request = rt };
var tulem = await cl.uploadMimeAsync(new uploadMimeRequest(ulreg,
                                   Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xml xml")));
```

throws SOAP error *body must have exactly one child element* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>Client.InvalidBody</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Malformed SOAP message: body must have exactly one child element</faultstring>
            <faultactor></faultactor>
            <detail>
                <faultDetail>1e2a2727-98f5-4d6d-ba1a-7a34dc6438fc</faultDetail>
            </detail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

.NET sends requests with two child elemnts in SOAP body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"></Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <uploadMime xmlns="http://emta-v6.x-road.eu">
            <request xmlns="">
                <target>target</target>
                <operation>operation</operation>
                <file href="href">786D6C20636F6E74656E74</file>
                <props />
            </request>
        </uploadMime>
        <attachment>eG1sIHhtbA==</attachment>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

How to create such request in ASP.NET MVC controller in .NET 8 ?

WSDL of service is in https://ncfailid.emta.ee/s/ad5sNbJtJ5RRfEK/download/uploadmime.wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://emta-v6.x-road.eu" xmlns:xrd="http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="mkrliides-uploader" targetNamespace="http://emta-v6.x-road.eu">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://emta-v6.x-road.eu">
            <import namespace="http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd" schemaLocation="http://x-road.eu/xsd/xroad.xsd"/>
            <element name="uploadMime">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="request" type="tns:UploadMimeRequestType"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <complexType name="UploadMimeRequestType">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="target" type="string">
                        <annotation>
                            <appinfo>
                                <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Teenuse nimi</xrd:title>
                                <xrd:notes xml:lang="et">Maksu- ja Tolliameti süsteemi lühinimi (TSD, KMD)</xrd:notes>
                            </appinfo>
                        </annotation>
                    </element>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="operation" type="string">
                        <annotation>
                            <appinfo>
                                <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Meetodi nimi</xrd:title>
                                <xrd:notes xml:lang="et">Käivitatava meetodi nimi (KinnitaDeklaratsioon)</xrd:notes>
                            </appinfo>
                        </annotation>
                    </element>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="file">
                        <complexType>
                            <simpleContent>
                                <extension base="hexBinary">
                                    <attribute name="href" type="string"/>
                                </extension>
                            </simpleContent>
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="props" type="tns:Properties">
                        <annotation>
                            <appinfo>
                                <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Manuse metaandmed</xrd:title>
                            </appinfo>
                        </annotation>
                    </element>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="Properties">
                <sequence>
                    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="prop">
                        <annotation>
                            <appinfo>
                                <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Parameetri väärtus</xrd:title>
                            </appinfo>
                        </annotation>
                        <complexType>
                            <simpleContent>
                                <extension base="string">
                                    <attribute name="key" type="string" use="required">
                                        <annotation>
                                            <appinfo>
                                                <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Parameetri nimi</xrd:title>
                                            </appinfo>
                                        </annotation>
                                    </attribute>
                                </extension>
                            </simpleContent>
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="uploadMimeResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="request" type="tns:UploadMimeRequestType"/>
                        <element name="response" type="tns:UploadMimeResponseType"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <complexType name="UploadMimeResponseType">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="messages" type="tns:CodeAndDescription">
                        <annotation>
                            <appinfo>
                                <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Kaugsüsteemi vastus</xrd:title>
                            </appinfo>
                        </annotation>
                    </element>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="CodeAndDescription">
                <sequence>
                    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="item">
                        <complexType>
                            <sequence>
                                <element name="code" type="string">
                                    <annotation>
                                        <appinfo>
                                            <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Kood</xrd:title>
                                        </appinfo>
                                    </annotation>
                                </element>
                                <element name="description" type="string">
                                    <annotation>
                                        <appinfo>
                                            <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Kirjeldus</xrd:title>
                                        </appinfo>
                                    </annotation>
                                </element>
                            </sequence>
                        </complexType>
                    </element>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="uploadMime">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:uploadMime" name="parameters"/>
        <wsdl:part name="attachment" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="uploadMimeResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:uploadMimeResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="xrdHeader">
        <wsdl:part element="xrd:client" name="client"/>
        <wsdl:part element="xrd:service" name="service"/>
        <wsdl:part element="xrd:id" name="id"/>
        <wsdl:part element="xrd:userId" name="userId"/>
        <wsdl:part element="xrd:issue" name="issue"/>
        <wsdl:part element="xrd:protocolVersion" name="protocolVersion"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="webServiceInterface">
        <wsdl:operation name="uploadMime">
            <wsdl:documentation>
                <xrd:title xml:lang="et">Failide edastamise teenus</xrd:title>
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:uploadMime"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:uploadMimeResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="soapBindings" type="tns:webServiceInterface">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="uploadMime">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <xrd:version>v1</xrd:version>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:multipartRelated xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/">
                    <mime:part>
                        <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="client" use="literal"/>
                        <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="service" use="literal"/>
                        <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="id" use="literal"/>
                        <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="protocolVersion" use="literal"/>
                        <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="userId" use="literal"/>
                        <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
                    </mime:part>
                    <mime:part>
                        <mime:content part="attachment" type="application/octet-stream"/>
                    </mime:part>
                </mime:multipartRelated>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="client" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="service" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="id" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="protocolVersion" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:xrdHeader" part="userId" use="literal"/>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="webService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:soapBindings" name="port">
            <soap:address location="http://SERVER_URL"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```